# What is the default username password of docker registry running from a container

Tags: docker

What is the default username password of docker registry running from a container ?

I tried admin/admin it is not working

Error response from daemon: Get https://host/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Comment: It doesn't say anything about the login data. You're connecting to a http server using https protocol.

Comment: Documentation about the Docker Registry, and how to configure basic auth can be found here https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#native-basic-auth

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix up authentication and encrypted traffic.

Login (authentication) could also happen using unencrypted traffic (but is highly insecure - everyone can see your credentials).

HttpS (usually using TLS) is about encrypting the traffic between client and server to prevent attackers to read your traffic. The server seems to respond to a request on https port (443) with unencrypted content. That means that there is probably some misconfiguration on the server side.